# Weird "Parsing JSON Request Failed" - jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I try to get JSON data from my server. But it works for some data and not working for some else.

I try to catch the error and it said Parsing JSON request failed.

this is the code

```
var url1 = 'http://example.com/example/bookdetail.php?id='+e;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url1,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        //do my stuff with the JSON data


    },error:function(x, e){
                  if (x.status === 0) {
                     alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network. ' + x.reponseText);
                  }
                  else if (x.status == 404) {
                     alert('Requested URL not found.');
                  } else if (x.status == 500) {
                     alert('Internel Server Error.');
                  } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                     alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                  } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                     alert('Request Time out.');
                  } else {
                     alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
                  }
          }

});
```

And this is the JSON format data

Parsing failed data

```
[{
    "id": "480",
    "title": "Cocokologi dalam Dunia Agama",
    "photo": "1374573181_cover.jpg",       
    "pdf": "http://example.com/example/1374573181.pdf",
    "desc": "Apakah teks-teks kitab suci sejalan atau cocok dengan pandangan-pandangan saintifik modern, seperti diklaim oleh banyak kaum agamawan pada masa kini? ..."
 }]
```

working JSON format

```
[{
  "id": "330",
  "title": "Demokrasi dan Kekecewaaan",
  "photo": "1374497593_cover.jpg",
  "pdf": "http://example.com/example/1374497593.pdf",
  "desc": "Buku ini bermula dari orasi ilmiah yang disampaikan Goenawan Mohamad (GM) dalam acara Nurcholish Madjid Memorial Lecture (NMML), yang berlang- sung di Aula Nurcholish Madjid, Universitas Paramadina, Jakarta, pada 23 Oktober 2008 lalu. Acara ini adalah acara tahunan Yayasan Wakaf Paramadina (YWP)—kali ini untuk kedua kali, setelah di tahun sebelumnya Dr. Komaruddin Hidayat menyampaikan orasi sejenis untuk pertama kali. Selain untuk mengenang sosok dan pemikiran Cak Nur, be- gitu biasa..."
  }]
```

This 2 types JSON is from same source but different result. Is there any false JSON format from the first JSON data?

STACK TRACE RESULT

```
This is from stack trace
x.extend.parseJSON (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
On (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
x.ajaxTransport.send.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
Paused on exception. "SystaxError"
```

JSON DATA

```
[{ "id" : "330", 
"title" : "Demokrasi dan Kekecewaaan", 
"photo" : "1374497593_cover.jpg", 
"pdf" : "http://example.com/books/1374497593.pdf", 
"desc" : "Buku ini bermula dari orasi ilmiah yang disampaikan Goenawan Mohamad (GM) dalam acara Nurcholish Madjid Memorial Lecture (NMML), yang berlang- sung di Aula Nurcholish Madjid, Universitas Paramadina, Jakarta, pada 23 Oktober 2008 lalu. Acara ini adalah acara tahunan Yayasan Wakaf Paramadina (YWP)—kali ini untuk kedua kali, setelah di tahun sebelumnya Dr. Komaruddin Hidayat menyampaikan orasi sejenis untuk pertama kali. Selain untuk mengenang sosok dan pemikiran Cak Nur, be- gitu biasa..." }
```

Comment: The JSON is correct. There is a problem somewhere else. Not in the JSON format.

Comment: What is the other error possibility?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly where the error is from the stacktrace?

Comment: Are you loading cross domain? If so, is the server responding with a valid JSONP looking response?

Comment: Yes, I use cross domain. It is work with the other data, like in the example, it is works with id = 330, but not works with id = 480

Comment: This is from stack trace
x.extend.parseJSON (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
On (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
x.ajaxTransport.send.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
Paused on exception. "SystaxError"

Comment: What is your server side script?

Comment: i guess the problem is with desc field. Try without that....

Comment: @user2449870: in your last example JSON lacks closing `]`. Is it another mistake or the actual response?

Comment: It is done. The problem is new line and it is done. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined `dataType: "json"` parameter and also using `error` callback method with AJAX, then AJAX would be check response header `Content-type`

You should set `text/json` header in server response..

PS: The second JSON is looks correct but sometime `space` or `enter ♪` might be come with response these character will not visible in response but these can be create issue with callback function.

Comment: Great, you are right. I try to use function to delete the enter and it's work. Thank you dude.