# JQuery AJAX unable to Parse response from PHP PDO method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fill a drop down list using JQuery AJAX and PHP. I have created a method in PHP which `echo`es a `json_encoded()` `array`. However, when the document is loaded it fails to get the result because of some `JSON` parsing error.

I am using a callable stored procedure in PHP and verified that it returns the correct result set when I tested the stored procedure in MySQL Workbench.

What could be causing this?

Error:

> Parsing JSON Request Failed

**RoleDaoImpl.php**

```
function getAllRoles()
{
    $roleList[] = "";
    try {
        $SQL = "CALL getAllRoles()";
        $sp_getAllRoles = $this->connection->prepare($SQL);
        $sp_getAllRoles->execute();

        $resultSet = $sp_getAllRoles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $roleId = $row['role_id'];
            $roleName = $row['role_name'];

            $roleList[] = array("roleId" => $roleId, "roleName" => $roleName);
        }
        echo json_encode($roleList);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**get_all_roles.php**

```
require_once '../../core/init.php';
$roleDaoImpl = new RoleDaoImpl($pdo);

$roleDaoImpl->getAllRoles();
```

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadRolesToDropDown();
});

function loadRolesToDropDown(){
    var url = 'get_all_roles.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            alert(response);
            $("#roledropdown").empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                var roleId = response[i]['roleId'];
                var roleName = response[i]['roleName'];
                $("#roledropdown").append("<option value='"+roleId+"'>"+roleName+"</option>");
            }
        },
        error : function(x,e){
            if (x.status==0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if(x.status==404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if(x.status==500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error.');
            } else if(e=='parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if(e=='timeout'){
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can't think of other ways to identify the cause. I'm fairly new with using AJAX with PHP. I'm using AJAX to avoid refreshing the page. Recently, I tried to follow some tutorials and still trying to get a grasp of how JQuery Ajax and PHP work together.

What other troubleshooting can I do?

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

***** EDIT ******

I tried printing log using `console.log()`  as in:

```
success: function(response){
    var len = response.length;
    alert(response);
    console.log(response);
    $("#roledropdown").empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var roleId = response[i]['roleId'];
        var roleName = response[i]['roleName'];
        $("#roledropdown").append("<option value='"+roleId+"'>"+roleName+"</option>");
    }
}
```

I get the ff on Google Chrome's console window.

> jquery-3.3.1.js:9488 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the
>   main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the
>   end user's experience. For more help, check
>   https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

[image]

Then, I inspected the this line `ajax   @jquery-3.3.1.js:9206`. And I get the ff. (*I don't know if it has something to do with parsing*)

```
try {
    completed = false;
    transport.send( requestHeaders, done );
    } catch ( e ) {
    // Rethrow post-completion exceptions
    if ( completed ) {
        throw e;
    }

    // Propagate others as results
    done( -1, e );
}
```

By the way, the drop down list is contained in a modal `div`. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the error. Something seemed to be deprecated as per the message shown in console window.

****** END OF EDIT ******

Comment: 1. in PHP what is contained in `$roleList` and 2. in the JS what is alerted when you alert the response? (you should actually `console.log(response)`)

Comment: Didn't you read this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750505/weird-parsing-json-request-failed-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750505/weird-parsing-json-request-failed-jquery) ?. Old but may be ...

Comment: @L.AlejandroM. Yeah, google brought me to that question earlier. I tried to replace `json` to `text/json` but got the same error message about parsing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I can't even get to display the alert message because it goes straight to the `error{}` block. The `$roleList` contains the array.

Comment: @Jordan - your server is sending something that doesn't look like JSON - it's that simple. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yeah, that's actually what I suspect. Probably during `json_encode($roleList)` I appreciate your answer. Should help me trace the cause. I'll update you once I've inspected every detail. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know how to troubleshoot this with the network panel as I showed below, then go back to your server and print out the contents of `$roleList`- we need to see whats there.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I checked what values are `echo`ed by calling `$roleDaoImpl->getAllRoles();` and I get this: `["",{"roleId":1,"roleName":"Administrator"},{"roleId":2,"roleName":"Teacher"},{"roleId":3,"roleName":"Student"}]` And I think, `ajax` is having problems parsing it to JSON why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot speak to your PHP output, but using placeholder data, I can easily confirm your JS does what you expect it to do. Below is your JS implemented using data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. It works as expected.

This indicates the output from your server is incorrect.  You can use the browser's developer tools to determine precisely what is being sent back from the server using the network tab. The image demonstrates this on this snippet.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadRolesToDropDown();
});

function loadRolesToDropDown(){
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            $("#roledropdown").empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                var id = response[i]['id'];
                var name = response[i]['name'];
                $("#roledropdown").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
            }
        },
        error : function(x,e){
            if (x.status==0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if(x.status==404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if(x.status==500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error.');
            } else if(e=='parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if(e=='timeout'){
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="roledropdown"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect json_encode() problems you must check if the function return false and then to use json_last_error() for to know about the reason.